# How to utilize "IN" statement with Linq <> ASP.NET MVC <> C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having struggles finding the best method to implement an IN statement.

Currently I am using the below code in my controller to return a list of stances specific an individual customer account.

```
return _context.Stances
               .ToList()
               .Select(Mapper.Map<Stances, StancesDto>)
               .Where(c => c.AccountGUID == userAccountID.CustomerGUID);
```

I am in the process of creating a partner portal that would allow a Partner user to have access to many other customer accounts that each individual customer provides them access to.

I setup a partnerLink table that stores a PartnerGUID and a CustomerGUID, marrying the relationship. The struggle I have is finding a method to allow a one to many relationship using an "IN" or "contains" option.

What I am looking to do is something like this:

either load the list if it is just a customer "OR" if it is a partner account Load all customer stances in the partnerLink table.

```
 var partners = _context.PartnerLinks
                        .Where(user => user.PartnerGUID == userAccountID.CustomerGUID)
                        .Select(user => user.AccountGUID) // extract the emails from users
                        .ToList();

  return _context.Stances
                 .ToList()
                 .Select(Mapper.Map<Stances, StancesDto>)
                 .Where(c => c.AccountGUID == userAccountID.CustomerGUID || partners.Contains(c.AccountGUID));
```

Comment: Do you know that you have loaded whole table into the memory?

Comment: No I am not aware of that I am loading whole table. What part is that?

Comment: Where you have `ToList` that immediately loads an entire table into memory. Also, you should map to a DTO after you have filtered what you want to retrieve. Generally, `Select` should be the last thing you do.

Comment: Do you think you can try to re-write what you want to accomplish more clearly?

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure to remove that in other areas as well

Comment: Actually `_context.PartnerLinks.ToList()`. ToList executes query to database. It should be latest operator in LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: Yes, I can make a few changes. I found some other code samples but it doesn't seem to be working still.

Comment: I made a few more changes to the main question. I found this article that represents what I am looking for.  https://dev.to/alexruzenhack/using-c-linq-api-to-perform-sql-in-logic-at-where-clause-i5f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `ToList` when combining LINQ queries. Everything should be IQueryable.

```cs
var partners = _context.PartnerLinks
    .Where(user => user.PartnerGUID == userAccountID.CustomerGUID)
    .Select(user => user.AccountGUID);

return _context.Stances
    .Where(c => c.AccountGUID == userAccountID.CustomerGUID || partners.Contains(c.AccountGUID))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(Mapper.Map<Stances, StancesDto>);
```

Also consider to use Automapper's `ProjectTo`

```cs
return _context.Stances
    .Where(c => c.AccountGUID == userAccountID.CustomerGUID || partners.Contains(c.AccountGUID))
    .ProjectTo<StancesDto>(configuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could do it with a Union.

Sometime like:

```
return _context.Stances.Select(Mapper.Map<Stances, StancesDto>).Where(c => c.AccountGUID == userAccountID.CustomerGUID)
.Union(_context.Stances.Select(Mapper.Map<Stances, StancesDto>).Where(c => partners.Contains(c.AccountGUID)));
```